# when dlopen one so, it's symbol is not covered by main symbol, why?

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors, ld

**libp2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void pixman()
{
    printf("pixman in libp1\n");
}
```

**libc2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void pixman();
void cairo()
{
    printf("cairo2\n");
    pixman();
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>


void pixman()
{
    printf("pixman in main\n");
}

int main()
{
    pixman();

    void* handle=NULL;
    void (*callfun)();

    handle=dlopen("/home/zpeng/test/so_test/libc2.so",RTLD_LAZY);
    callfun = (void(*)())dlsym(handle, "cairo");
    callfun();
...
}
```

**compile**

```
gcc -c  libp2.c -fPIC   -olibp2.o
rm libp2.a
ar -rs libp2.a libp2.o
gcc -shared -fPIC libc2.c  ./libp2.a -o libc2.so
gcc main.c  -ldl -L.  -g
```

the result:

```
pixman in main
cairo2
pixman: libp2
```

**why the last is not "pixman in main"?**

I see the symbols processing(LD_DEBUG=symbols), it begins with :

```
21180:     symbol=pixman;  lookup in file=./a.out
21180:     symbol=pixman;  lookup in file=/lib64/libdl.so.2
21180:     symbol=pixman;  lookup in file=/lib64/tls/libc.so.6
21180:     symbol=pixman;  lookup in file=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
21180:     symbol=pixman;  lookup in file=/home/zpeng/test/so_test/libc2.so
```

if I add -lc2 or -rdynamic to gcc main cmd , it will generate:

```
pixman in main
cairo2
pixman in main
```

***My questions:***

why lookup symbol in a.out but not get the result and continue to search libc2.so when without -rdynamic and -lc2 ?

Comment: Your library libc2 knows knothing about pixman in main - it is compiled together with your static library libp2. Once your compiled main with -rdynamic, it finds the first defined version of pixman. I would guess though you also get a linker warning. My suggestion is to always use the keyword extern, when this type of behavior is desired

Comment: exactly, as you compile `cairo` before `main`, the `cairo` can't possibly know that function `pixman` will be reimplemented, hence the binary `libc2.so` contains "hardcoded behaviour for function pixman". So when you consequently use it indirectly from `main` it behaves exactly the same way it was compiled to behave. I believe using `-Wall` could give some warning, but not sure here.

Comment: I found that when add pixman in dynsym by using -lotherlib(which includes pixman) or -rdynamic, then cairo will call main's pixman.    About current example, the pixman symbol only exist in .symtab not in .dynsym.  Why symbol find begin from dynsym other then global symbol table

Answer (score 2):

**Why the last is not "pixman in main"?**
That's because shared libraries have their own global offset table or GOT. When you use the cairo function in libc2.so, the pixman function that will be called is the same function that was resolved when compiling the .so file in the first place.

That is:

```
# creates object file only -- contains first pixman implementation
gcc -c  libp2.c -fPIC   -olibp2.o

# just turns the object file into an archive
ar -rs libp2.a libp2.o

# creates the .so file -- all symbols in libc2.c are resolved here 
# and you passed in the .a file for that purpose. The .a file containing the
# first pixman implementation gets put in libc2.so.
gcc -shared -fPIC libc2.c  ./libp2.a -o libc2.so
```

After this, anyone using libc2.so will get the copy stored in libc2.so. The lookup order you post is for a.out I believe and it's right. It looks for pixman in a.out, then libc2.so, and so on.

**Why lookup symbol in a.out but not get the result and continue to search libc2.so when without -rdynamic and -lc2?**
The rdynamic option loads ALL symbols to the dynamic symbol table -- not just the ones it thinks are used (lc2 has the same effect). When you load all those symbols you have a conflict -- the pixman function. The main.c implementation is used in this case. As others have pointed out, this will probably generate a warning.

Comment: even though I don't find materials that suggest symbol lookup in dynmaic library start from the.dynsym of a.out, I believe it's right by test.    thank you for description about the effect of -rdynamic and -l**

Comment: @zpeng The man page for dlopen touches on this a little: "If the executable was linked with the flag "-rdynamic" (or, synonymously, "--export-dynamic"), then the global symbols in the executable will also be used to resolve references in a dynamically loaded library." Not sure if there is clear documentation on the -lc2 case, since it's atypical to both dlopen and add -l* for the same library.

Comment: Thank your remainder. I lookup "--export-dynamic" in man of ld.                "When creating a dynamically linked executable, add all symbols to the dynamic symbol  table.  The dynamic symbol table is the set of symbols which are visible from
           dynamic objects at run time.

           If you do not use this option, the dynamic symbol table will normally contain only those symbols which are referenced by some dynamic object mentioned in the link."    About dlopen and -l open the same library, -l's effect override the dlopen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile the sources that get archived into the .a file with `-fvisibility=hidden`, to indicate that, although they are global functions, they are not meant to be used outside the resulting library but are instead meant to resolve symbols inside the library. That will cause the symbols in the .a file to appear with the qualifier " t " in `nm -a` instead of " T ", which is used for symbols available to other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It just auto binded to **LOCAL symbol**,

Since there not `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` explicit in libp2.c, the compiler auto bind this function calling to LOCAL **.symtab**, instead of **.dynsym**

appendix1: more about ELF header: `readelf -s xxx.lib`
appendix2: keyword of ld argument `-Bsymbolic-functions`